# Why is map function not effective?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I am not struck or anything, but I feel this weird. Below is the code snippet I have worked on:

```
from hashClass import HashTable

a = HashTable(11)
input_value = list((54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20))

map(lambda x: a.put(x,x),input_value))
print(a.data)
```

I have created my own hash table class. It has a method called put which accepts key-value pair and "HashTable.data" attribute displays all the values in the table.

It works completely fine when I use put method with normal key-value pairs. I know that the solution can be implemented using:

```
for i in input_value: a.putt(i,i)
```

But I would like to know why the map function is not effective? When I try to map every input_value with "put" method, it has to add the value to the instance if I am not wrong. My reason is I may not be using the mapped value but syntactically when I am mapping, it is supposed to update the instance variable.

Below is the hash Class I have created for reference.

```
class HashTable(object):

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size = size
        self.slots = self.size*[None]
        self.data = self.size*[None]
        self.values = 0

    def put(self,key,value):
        hashValue = self.hashFunction(key)
        if self.slots[hashValue] == None:
            self.slots[hashValue] = key
            self.data[hashValue] = value
            self.values += 1
        elif self.slots[hashValue] == key:
            self.data[hashValue] = value
        else:
            hashValue = self.reHash(hashValue)
            while self.slots[hashValue] != None and self.slots[hashValue] != key:
                hashValue = self.reHash(hashValue)
            self.slots[hashValue] = key
            self.data[hashValue] = value
            self.values += 1


    def reHash(self,oldValue):
        return (oldValue+1)%self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.values


    def get(self,key):
        hashValue = self.hashFunction(key)
        if self.slots[hashValue] == None:
            return "No Value associated"
        elif self.slots[hashValue] == key:
            return self.data[hashValue]


    def hashFunction(self,key):
        return key%self.size
```

Comment: Your `map` line seems to have an extra right paren?

Comment: I suspect you're using Python 3, where `map` returns an iterator. So `map` won't call the function until you iterate over the map iterator. However, you shouldn't use `map` purely for side-effects like this.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yeah, this makes sense. I am using python3

Comment: Similarly, it's bad style to do something like this `[a.put(x,x) for x in input_value]`, since it's using a list comprehension for the side-effect of the method call and you don't actual want the list, which is probably full of `None`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you are using Python3.

With python3, a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) facilitates lazy evaluation, meaning it will *not* carry out its functionality unless it really needs to. What you are trying to do is use a `map` to produce side effects. Sure, you can do this with:

```
list(map(lambda x: a.put(x,x), input_value)))
```

The `list()` forces evaluation to take place.

However, using `map` for side effects is somewhat of an anti-pattern. I would prefer something clearer and more idiomatic such as the `for` loop you mentioned.

---

As an example:

```
In [854]: s = set()

In [862]: m = map(lambda x=x: s.add(x), [1, 2, 3])

In [863]: s
Out[863]: set()
```

Nothing happened to `s` thus far. Now, apply `list()` to the `map` object.

```
In [864]: list(m)
Out[864]: [None, None, None]
```

The `None`s are classic symptoms of side-effects. However...

```
In [865]: s
Out[865]: {1, 2, 3}
```

So, it works. But it certainly doesn't look good.

Comment: This is a huge change, will never dear to change to python3 then :D more over, does an assignment like `l = map(...)` trigger the lazy evaluation? don't have a python3 to try.

Comment: should be `m = map(lambda x: s.add(x), [1, 2, 3])` in your example by the way, can't edit the answer cause the 6 characters rule didn't meet

Comment: @armnotstrong 1. It does not, and 2. It is valid syntax - a scope specifier for the lambda.

Comment: check the version on the screenshot, it's Python3.6.2

Comment: LOL, that's why people don't turn to python3 :D

Comment: @armnotstrong You have `x=x` which fails because you don't have a variable `x` defined.

Comment: @StevenSummers need that be pre defined in a lambda function?

Comment: `lamda x: ...` and `lambda x=x: ...` are slightly different your are specifying a kwarg with a default value instead `def func(x = x)` vs `def func(x = None)`. But it fails because it doesn't know what the `x` on the right hand side should be since it's undefined.